# Numbering triples

Tags: algorithm, math, hash

Given three integers : x, y, z.
I want to find paginated function F : (x,y,z) -> N, where N is a natural number.
That is, I want to numbered all such tuples of 3 elements.

I heard about Cantor numbering, but there are other options to function quickly calculated and gave adequately large values​​?

P.s. I want to construct a hash thus

Comment: Should f(x,y,z) be equal to f(y,x,z) ? (et cetera)

Comment: No, f(x,y,z) != f(y,x,z)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider 3D-variant of [Z-order curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve). It's rather easy to calculate Morton index of triplet with bit arithmetics.
Example:

```
X  = xk..x1x0 (binary bits)
Y  = yl..y1y0 (binary bits)
Z  = zm..z1z0 (binary bits)
3D index(X,Y,Z) = (...z1y1x1z0y0x0)
X=2=10b, Y=3=11b, Z=4=100b
I = 100 011 010 b = 282 dec
```

Comment: Excellent, looks good. I figured out how to apply it to the two numbers. Could you show how to do it for three?

Comment: @Dima00782 example added

Answer (score 1):

Cantor numbering (as referred to in the OP) orders pairs `(x,y)` as follows:

```
0,0
0,1
1,0
0,2
1,1
2,0
...
```

That is, the pairs are sorted first by their sum and then by the first element. The index of a given pair can easily be computed:

`C(x,y) = ((x + y)2 + x + y)/2 + x`

You can use generalize that to larger tuples in various ways, but a simple one is to apply the numbering sequentially:

`C3(x,y,z) = C(C(x,y),z)`

Cantor numbering has two major advantages:

1. It does not depend on limiting the values to a given range.
2. It is a compact numbering, so the indices do not grow too rapidly.

Answer (score 0):

As long as `x, y, z` are low or mid value, hash method can work just like this :

Example when `x,y,z < 1000` :

```
x*1000*1000 + y*1000 + z
```

Comment: Works fine as long as `a,b,c in (-1000,1000)` (fast and simple solution if you know that your values are within the valid range).

Answer (score 0):

If your values are not too big, you could use [Gödel-numbering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering).

In your case:

```
F(x,y,z) = 2^x * 3^y * 5^z;   // ^ means power function (not xor)
```

Its not very cheap to calculate (because of the usage of the power function) but it guarantees to be [injective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) (=> collision free hash-function).

Answer (score 0):

If `x,y,z` can each be represented by `n` bits, you can construct a number composed out of `3n` bits, which will be a concatenation of the bits of `x,y,z`: the first `n` bits will represent `x`, then bits `n+1` to `2n` will represent `y` and `2n+1` to `3n` will represent `z`.

In this case (`x,y,z` can be represented by `n` bits) you may have up to `((2^n)^3) = 2^3n` combinations of `x,y,z`, so this gives a pretty tight bound on the size (in terms of bits) of the output of `f` (you won't be able to use much less bits than `3n` to represent the output of `f`).